# Why don't these statements work, if I make some changes

Tags: c++

```
// The right code

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int len = 100000;
vector<int> qus;            //Array to sort
int buf[len];               //Array that stores results

void count_sort(){
    fstream output;
    output.open("output.data", ios::out);    //output file
    
    int max = qus[0], min = qus[0];         // max number and min number
    for(auto x : qus){
        if(x > max)
            max = x;
        if(x < min)
            min = x;
    }

    vector<int> count(max - min + 1, 0);    //Array that count
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ){         // count
        count[qus[i] - min]++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i ++ ){         //Prefix sum. if you know how many numbers there are in front, you can determine the position of this value
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        buf[count[qus[i] - min]-1] = qus[i];        //Stores results. Put each number in the corresponding position.
        count[qus[i] - min] --;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){                      //output the results. 
        
        output << buf[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;   // don't work
    output.close();
}

int main(){
    fstream data;
    data.open("input.data", ios::in);  //input file
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){ 
        int buf1;    
        data >> buf1;
        qus.push_back(buf1);
    }
    count_sort();
    
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

```
// Error code 1
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int len = 100000;
vector<int> qus;            //Array to sort
int buf[len];               //Array that stores results

void count_sort(){
    
    fstream output;
    
    
    int max = qus[0], min = qus[0];         // max number and min number
    for(auto x : qus){
        if(x > max)
            max = x;
        if(x < min)
            min = x;
    }

    vector<int> count(max - min + 1, 0);    //Array that count
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ){         // count
        count[qus[i] - min]++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i ++ ){         //Prefix sum. if you know how many numbers there are in front, you can determine the position of this value
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        buf[count[qus[i] - min]-1] = qus[i];        //Stores results. Put each number in the corresponding position.
        count[qus[i] - min] --;
    }


    output.open("output.data", ios::out);           //output file
    if(!output) cout << "Error";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){                      //output the results.
        output << buf[i] << endl;
    }

    

}

int main(){
    ifstream data("input.data", ios::in);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){ 
        int buf1;    
        data >> buf1;
        qus.push_back(buf1);
    }
    count_sort();
    

    cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;   // don't work
    return 0;
}
```

```
//Error code 2
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int len = 100000;
vector<int> qus;            //Array to sort
int buf[len];               //Array that stores results

void count_sort(){
    int max = qus[0], min = qus[0];         // max number and min number
    for(auto x : qus){
        if(x > max)
            max = x;
        if(x < min)
            min = x;
    }

    vector<int> count(max - min + 1, 0);    //Array that count
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ){         // count
        count[qus[i] - min]++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i ++ ){         //Prefix sum. if you know how many numbers there are in front, you can determine the position of this value
        count[i] += count[i - 1];
    }

    for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        buf[count[qus[i] - min]-1] = qus[i];        //Stores results. Put each number in the corresponding position.
        count[qus[i] - min] --;
    }
}

int main(){
    ifstream data("input.data", ios::in);
    ofstream output("output.data", ios::out);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){ 
        int buf1;    
        data >> buf1;
        qus.push_back(buf1);
    }
    count_sort();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ ){                      //output the results.
        output << buf[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;   // don't work
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]

This is the code for Count Sort. Data size is form 0 ~ 9999 . There are 100,000 numbres in total.
The results of the code are correct.
But if I change the code to the form in the two images, the code cannot output any results. And the sentence `cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;` don't work in any case.
So I have three questions.
Why the code don't work, if I make changes according to the two pictures.
And why the sentence `cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;` don't work.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `fstream data; data.open("input.data", ios::in);` to `fstream data("input.data", ios::in);`. Also, since the comment says this is an "input stream", write it that way: `ifstream data("input.data");`. And, finally, you don't need to call `data.close();`; the destructor will do that. Same thing for `fstream output`.

Comment: `cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl; ` if it doesn't work what did it do? Not print anything, print the wrong value, compiler error? With that said I prefer std::chrono for timing: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)

Comment: So you posted code that works, and then posted a picture of code that doesn't work? Just post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Don't post working code either. If you have code that doesn't work, make a [mcve] of it and post it as text.

Comment: In all of the cases you should explain what "doesn't work" means because without an explanation we have to guess what the program is doing.

Comment: You open the file twice. Once in `main()` and once in `count_sort()` without closing it in between opens.

Comment: You can add a parameter to pass the open file to `void count_sort(){` like this `void count_sort(fstream & output){` then don't try to reopen it in count sort and call it from main like this `count_sort(output);` instead of `count_sort();`

Comment: Sorry. I've posted the code now. And I did some tests. I found that if the amount of data becomes smaller, it will not have errors. I think the errors are about the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The people here want to help you. But you need to answer to the comments. You need to communicate.

I will answer your question:

You are trying to open the output stream twice. Then, in the output stream, a failbit is set. And the output stream will stop working from then on. It will never output something, because you made a mistake before.

And to answer your question from the title:

> Why don't these statements work, if I make some changes

These statements do not work, because you created bugs while changing.

Additionally, the code does also not work, because of its low quality in respect to design, variable names and comments.

`std::cout << (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`  works on my computer. But becuase you did not post the complete code, I cannot solve the problem. By the way. `clock()* is a C-function and should **not** be used in C++.

See? If you would listen, then people could help you.

Comment: Sorry. I've posted the code now. And I did some tests. I found that if the amount of data becomes smaller, it will not have errors. I think the errors are about the memory.

Comment: When the amount of data is more than 100,000 , I use other sorting algorithms without errors. In theory, they use the same size of space. I can't find the reason for the error.